# date query in wordpress search with WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to Building An Advanced WordPress Search With WP_Query according to [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/) article.

I use shortcode to build a form search.

```
 function sm_setup() {
    add_shortcode( 'sm_search_form', 'sm_search_form' );
}add_action('init','sm_setup');
```

Then register custom query vars

```
function sm_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'cat';
    $vars[] = 'timestart';
    $vars[] = 'timeend';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'sm_register_query_vars' );
```

I Build a custom query based on several conditions:

```
function sm_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // check if the user is requesting an admin page
    // or current query is not the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){
        return;
    }
    // edit the query only when post type is 'accommodation'
    // if it isn't, return
    if ( !is_post_type_archive( 'post' ) ){
        return;
    }
    $date_query = array();
    // get query var values
    // defaults to empty string
    if( !empty( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ) ){
        $query->set( 'cat', get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    }


     // get date query var values

  $date_query[] = array( 'after' => get_query_var( 'timestart') ,'inclusive'=>'true');
  $date_query[] = array( 'before' => get_query_var( 'timeend'),'inclusive'=>'true');

    $date_query['relation'] = 'AND';

        $query->set( 'date_query', $date_query );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sm_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

And finally search form

```
function sm_search_form( $args ){
    // The Query
    // meta_query expects nested arrays, even if you only have one query
    // to add the category param
    $sm_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
    // The Loop
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'parent' => 0
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    if( count($categories) == 0){
        return;
    }
    asort($categories);


    $cat_option = '<select name="cat">';
    $cat_option .= '<option value="">' . __( 'choose category','my_plugin' ) . '</option>';
    foreach ($categories as $category ) {
        $cat_option .= '<option value="' . $category->cat_ID . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</option>';
    }
    $cat_option .= '</select>' . "\n";
    reset($categories);




    $output = '<form id="smform" action="' . esc_url( home_url() ) . '" method="GET" role="search">';
    $output .= '<div class="smtextfield">' . '<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search key..." value="' . get_search_query() . '" /></div>';
    $output .= '<div class="smtextfield">' . '<input type="text" name="timestart" placeholder="timestart..."/></div>';
    $output .= '<div class="smtextfield">' . '<input type="text" name="timeend" placeholder="timeend..." /></div>';
    $output .= '<div class="smselectbox">' . $cat_option . '</div>';
    $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />';
    $output .= '<p><input type="submit" value="Go!" class="button" /></p></form>';
    return $output;
}
```

My problem is date_query! when I want customize with date. search dose not work! and show all posts.

Where did I make mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of date_query is wrong here:
'inclusive' should be outside of internal arrays. Before and after can be in the same array if compared column is default:

```
    $date_query[] = array( 
     'after' => get_query_var( 'timestart'),
     'before' => get_query_var('timeend')
    );

   $date_query['relation'] = 'AND';
   $date_query['inclusive'] = true;
```

And make sure that get_query_var values are correct. Check the syntax here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

f.e. print them before the query. echo get_query_var( 'timestart'); - see if they are displayed correctly.

Comment: values send with this syntax YYYY-mm-dd . for example 2017-08-01

Comment: then my code should work for you. it is working&tested code. if it doesn't work, then add your final var_dump($args) to your question, and i will check if anything is wrong there

Comment: where I put var_dump?